# Adding menus to child preference screens

Tags: android

I have a menu that comes up for my PreferenceActivity. In my child preference screens, I lose that menu (doesn't pop up). How can I make my menu pop up for children too?

Thanks.

Example:

```
<PreferenceScreen
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:persistent="true">
  <PreferenceCategory
    android:title="some category"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:orderingFromXml="true">
    <PreferenceScreen
      android:title="some child screen"
      android:summary="some child summary">
      <PreferenceCategory
         ...
```

The first preference screen has the menu, but when you click on the child one, no menu. How can you add the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the similar issue. Here is what I did to overcome the issue.

In the preferenceActivity onCreate method,

```
        final PreferenceScreen childPref = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference("childPrefId");
        childPref .setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(PreferenceActivity.this, YourSettings.class);
                intent.setAction("ShowChildPref");
                startActivity(intent);                    
                return true;
            }
        });

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals("ShowChildPref"))
        {                
            setPreferenceScreen(childPref);

            /*Set Flags here based on intent what kind of menu to create in OnPrepareMenu.*/
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I wish they would clear all this up. If PreferenceScreen wasn't so convenient I would just make my own ListActivity cause that seems a little easier then this.

Answer (score 3):

I have better solution because Suriya's suffer from double showing of child's PreferenceScreen.

For child PreferenceScreen I use same PreferenceActivity. So at first for a child PreferenceScreen where we want to use option menu we set intent to our PreferenceActivity in onCreate method:

```
ourPreferenceScreen = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference("our_preference_screen");
if (ourPreferenceScreen != null) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PreferenceActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("ShowOurPreferenceScreen", true);
    ourPreferenceScreen.setIntent(intent);
}
```

Then later in a same onCreate method we detect if our PreferenceActivity is started with extra flag. If so we switch to wanted PreferenceScreen:

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("ShowOurPreferenceScreen", false)) {
    setPreferenceScreen(ourPreferenceScreen);
    return;
}
```

And at the end we hande onCreateOptionMenu and other related option menu methods like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (getPreferenceScreen().equals(ourPreferenceScreen)) {
        // your menu code
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the code for the menu in each class that might want to bring up a menu using the menu button.  Just because the other activity is in the background does not mean the menu will launch.  It needs to be set in each class that wil be forground and need the menu available.

Comment: Maybe I wasnt clear ... I have a PreferenceActivity that inflates preferences from XML (and contains among other things, child preference screens). The activity creates the menus, but when you click on a preference that is contained in a Preference Screen, it doesnt have any menu items. Can I specify in the XML to include parent menus (looked and didnt see that I could, so probably not)?